# Check which checkbox is checked/Unchecked in android

Tags: android, checkbox

I am creating checkboxes at runtime but i don't know how to find that which checkbox is checked and which is unchecked?This is the code.

```
for (String s : options)
{
   chk = new CheckBox(this);
   System.out.println(s);
   chk.setId(i++);
   chk.setText(s);  
   selected=s;
   chk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
     DisplayToast(selected);
else
     DisplayToast(selected);
}
});
lm.addView(chk);
}
```

Comment: You could simply store the generated CheckBoxes in a list. Then iterate and call isChecked() on each

Comment: You can also iterate `lm` for all the views, check if they're `instanceof` checkbox, cast them to CheckBox and check if they're checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the `id` of `CheckBox` using `getId()` method ..

```
CheckBox checkBox = ((CheckBox) v);

if (checkBox.isChecked())
{
    int checkBoxId = checkBox.getId(); // It will give you checked checkbox id..
    DisplayToast(selected);
}
else
     DisplayToast(selected);
```

**Update:**

To get all CheckBox states you have to iterate thru `ChildViews` of `lm` layout.

Something like,

```
for (int i = 0; i < lm.getChildCount(); i++) {
    View v = lm.getChildAt(i);
    if (v instanceof CheckBox) {
      if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked())
      // Check Checkbox
      else
      // Unchecked Checkbox
    } 
}
```

**Note:** I would suggest you can use `onCheckedChangeListener` instead of `View.OnClickListener()` to check - uncheck event of `CheckBox`. (But it is optional, it also works with `OnClickListener`)

Answer (score 3):

You should use `onCheckedChangeListener` to define whether your checkbox checked:

```
chk.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            //checked
        } else {
            //not checked
        }
    }
});
```